# How do I control the size of a UIViews background pattern colour?

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, uicolor

I have set a patterned background on my UIView using:

```
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundImage.png"]];
```

But the image appears to be stretched or scaled up and doesn't appear at the desired resolution. Is there a way to set the size or scale of a background pattern? Or is the images size used as a default. Does the image DPI have an affect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I wasn't using the @2x naming convention so images were appearing stretched. I added it in and it fixed everything.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern is constructed by tiling the image until it fills the given area. 
So there is no control on tile size other than the original image dimensions.

Now, if you want to provide retina images you should just have a `@2x` version and iOS will take care of that automatically (btw change the method call to `[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundImage"]` - the file extension is optional for png images).

**Do not** provide higher dpi images for retina, instead provide an image that is twice the size of the non-retina one (and obviously not by oversampling the image).

Finally the only control you seem to have on the pattern (at least the only one that is documented) is the phase. Here is the relevant part from the [official documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> By default, the phase of the returned color is 0, which causes the top-left corner of the image to be aligned with the drawing origin. To change the phase, make the color the current color and then use the CGContextSetPatternPhase function to change the phase.